# Overload a toString Method

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, tostring

I'm trying to write a toString method for a class with multiple constructors:

```
public Fraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2)
{
    num1=n1;
    den1=d1;
    num2=n2;
    den2=d2;
}
```

and

```
public Fraction(int nAns, int dAns)
{
    nAnswer=nAns;
    dAnswer=dAns;
}
```

However, when I try to write a toString, I keep getting compilation errors when I do (probably because both methods are called toString):

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Fraction[numerator1="+num1+", numerator2="+num2+", denominator1="+den1+", denominator2="+den2+"]";
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Fraction[nAnswer="+nAnswer+", dAnswer="+dAnswer+"]";
}
```

If I name one of the toString methods toString and the other one toString2, the program compiles but doesn't give me the desired output for toString2.

So I then tried writing an if statement for this method, but I'm not sure how I would write the if part (how do I say "If your fraction looks like the first constructor, return the first toString; if your fraction looks like the second constructor, return the second toString"?).

I tried the following, but I know that the if part is wrong because I keep getting compilation errors:

```
if Fraction==Fraction(int num1, int den1, int num1, int den2)
{
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Fraction[numerator1="+num1+", numerator2="+num2+", denominator1="+den1+", denominator2="+den2+"]";
    }
else if Fraction==Fraction(int nAnswer, int dAnswer)
{
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Fraction[nAnswer="+nAnswer+", dAnswer="+dAnswer+"]";
    }
}
```

But I know that an overloaded toString method is possible because so many classes in the Java library use it (for example, the Rectangle class).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At least 10 compiler errors in your code.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I know that my code has compiler errors, namely in the if statement. However, since I'm still a beginner programmer, I'm not sure how to fix these errors. The main part I need help with is how to code the if statement so that the it says what I mentioned in the quotes above.

Comment: At least give compiler errors - and try to understand.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded brash earlier. It was not at all my intention. Anyway, I'll keep playing around with my code and try to find a solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, `toString` method comes from object class, don't try to make multiple of those methods or anything like that, have everything in one method. As to your problem, you can make a variable `String description` for your class, and initialize it in constructor and then in `toString` just return that variable. You can do that if you are not changing your object any other way after creating them, but that's probably not the case. You can also make two boolean variables `createdByFirstConstructor` and `createdBySecondConstructor` and initialize them with false. Then in both constructors change corrseponding variable to `true` and then in `toString` just check which variable is set to true and print accordingly. Hope this helps. There is probably easier solution, but it's not coming to my mind right now, maybe later.

```java
private boolean createdByFirst = false;
private boolean createdBySecond = false;

public Fraction(yourCode){
  createdByFirst = true;
}

public Fraction(yourOtherCode){
  createdBySecond = true;
}

public String toString(){
  if(createdByFirst)
    return "yourStringForFirstConstructor";
  else if(createdBySecond)
    return "yourStringForSecondConstructor";
  else
    return "Something else";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this

Comment: Update: I just tried this code, and although I'm still getting compilation errors, at least it's a jumping-off point I can play around with. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When your teacher told you to try and see how you could model two different kinds of fractions, they did not mean to try and cram both implementations into the same class with two constructors and two completely unrelated sets of member variables.  That makes about as much sense as a flying toaster.

Your teacher wants you to demonstrate that you understand how to create a base `Fraction` class which defines the interface of a fraction without any implementation, and then write two subclasses, (look up the `extends` keyword,) one which does fractions one way, and another which does fractions a different way.  Each subclass will have its own constructor, its own set of member variables, and of course its own `toString()` method, so everything will be fine.

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying. The original assignment was to create a base Fraction class. However, since I'm in a beginner's programming class, my teacher modified the assignment to the version that I have above (with both numerators and denominators in the same constructor). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Numerators and denominators in the same constructor is one thing.  A set of member variables initialized by one constructor, and a set of unrelated member variables initialized by another constructor, is totally another thing.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I misinterpreted your comment the first time around. Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but if my second set of variables (nAnswer and dAnswer) are derived from the first set of variables (num1, den1, num2, den2) in a method class (for example: nAnswer=num1*den2+num2*den1), is that still a problem? Thanks for your help. As a beginner, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, so `nAnswer` and `dAnswer` are supposed to be some kind of results.  Then I suppose you do not need two subclasses, only one should suffice.  `nAnswer` and `dAnswer` would be in the base (super) class, the rest would be in the subclass.  In the subclass you can do `nAnswer=num1*den2+num2*den1` if `nAnswer` has been declared as `protected` in the base class.  ("Protected" means that derived classes may access it.)

Comment: So, the `toString()` of the base class would return the string representation of `nAnswer` and `dAnswer`, while the `toString()` of the subclass would return the string representation of everything.  Hint: you can do `super.toString()` to invoke the `toString()` of the base class from within the `toString()` of the subclass.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me! I'll try the super.toString() method and see where it takes me.